# Setting a new keybind shortcut makes Copy to not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code I have created a keybind shortcut 'CTRL+C A' and that makes a Copy keybind (CTRL+C) to stop wroking. How I could fix this?

Comment: Which command are you triggering with the keybinding?

Comment: The command doesn't matter, whatever command I use, Copy doesn't work. But if you want to know it is amxxpawn.compile from AMXXPawn Language extension.